# How does variance change if i change the individual elements of a population

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics

If I know the variance of the population. And then i multiply every element of the population by 2 and divide by 10. what happens to the variance?

Comment: When I read the subject line I thought you might be proposing to change _one_ of the numbers in the list and then asking how the variance changes when that is done. What you're doing is a lot simpler than that. One thing you should recall from elementary arithmetic is that if you multiply them all by $2$ and then divide them all by $10$, that's the same as just dividing them all by $5$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Comment: @ugradmath How is multiplying by 2 and dividing by 10 any different from just dividing by 5? Why the need for those two separate steps?

Answer (score 3):

You get the answer by looking at the definition of variance:
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2
$$
So what happens when $x_i \rightarrow \frac{2}{10}x_i$?  The answer is that
$$ 
\frac{1}{n}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\sum(\frac{2}{10}x_i - \frac{2}{10} \bar{x})^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum{\left ( \frac{2}{10} \right )^2 (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$
That tells you what happens to the variance.

Comment: You forgot to divide by the number of observations.

Comment: Good point; fixed.  There's also the small point that when $\bar{x}$ is estimated by taking the mean of the collected data, then you divide by $n-1$, but when $\bar{x}$ is known *a priori*, then you divide by $n$.